# Multisite - Commerce reference between sites

Tags: commerce, multi-sites

### Setup

Main website: www.example.com
LMS website: lms.example.com

- The Main website is public facing for visitors to browse the courses.
- The LMS website is for the users/commerce to be managed and the actual Course material to be used/viewed.
  Drupal Commerce manages the payments and Access modules manage the users access once purchased.

The 2 websites are setup as Drupal multi-sites:

- On the same server
- Separate databases
- All modules/theme files are under the sites/all folder.

### Question

How do I create a 'Buy' button on the main website that will take the visitor to the LMS website with that particular course added in their cart?

Note: there is only a hand full of courses so the link on the main website can be manually added for each course.

Comment: The subdomain is currently setup as a multisite. If this makes this impossible/very hard, then I could use Domain Access to create the subdomain LMS under the same Drupal install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have discovered that I will need to create a Rule using the module Rules URL Argument that will take the URL /add-to-cart/[SKU] and add this to cart.

I can create a field on the main site for the SKU and this then outputs the link to the LMS website.

The source is here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Rn7FLFytTU